# Toolbar isn't following into next activity

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app and I would like to have a toolbar going into each and every activity. I set up the toolbar into the primary activity, but when I click the item in the toolbar that sends me to the next activity, the toolbar isn't shown. I have included the toolbar in both .xml files. When I run the second activity by itself, the toolbar is shown. Any help please?

HomeActivty Java:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);







}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home,menu);

return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
int res_id = item.getItemId();
if(res_id == R.id.action_profile)
{
    Intent profileActivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, 
ProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(profileActivity);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, 
R.anim.push_left_out);


}
else if(res_id == R.id.action_home)
{

}
else if(res_id == R.id.action_msg)
{
    Intent cnectActivity = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, 
ConnectionsActivity.class);
    startActivity(cnectActivity);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, 
R.anim.push_left_out);
}

return true;
}
}
```

ProfileActivity java:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home,menu);

return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
int res_id = item.getItemId();
if(res_id == R.id.action_profile)
{



}
else if(res_id == R.id.action_home)
{
    Intent profileActivity = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, 
    HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(profileActivity);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, 
    R.anim.push_left_out);
}
else if(res_id == R.id.action_msg)
{
    Intent cnectActivity = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, 
    ConnectionsActivity.class);
    startActivity(cnectActivity);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, 
    R.anim.push_left_out);
}

return true;
}
}
```

toolbar xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/AppThemePenis"
android:elevation="4dp"

>


<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="P"/>



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Please add the activity parts of your AndroidManifest file and the styles.xml.